# "for" loop on NodeList to change className

Tags: javascript, html, css

This should take each element of `class="one_level"` and change its `className` to `four_level`. But this doesn't happen. Only this first list item is getting its appearance changed, the second is still the same.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>DOCUMENT OBJECT MODEL</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="one_level" style="background-color:black; color:white; margin:5px; ">ONE</li>
            <li class="one_level" style="background-color:black; color:white; margin:5px ">TWO</li>
            <li class="two_level" style="background-color:orange; color:red; margin:5px">THREE</li>
            <li class="two_level" style="background-color:orange; color:red; margin:5px">FOUR</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="getValues"></div>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.four_level{
    border:solid 5px orange;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 6px;
}
.five_level{
    border:solid 5px pink;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 6px;
}
```

JS:

```
//Get elements for class: one_level
var classOneSet = document.getElementsByClassName("one_level");
var lengthList = classOneSet.length;

//Change appearance
var i;
for (i = 0; i < lengthList; i++){
    classOneSet.item(i).className = "four_level";
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend renaming this question to something that actually describes your problem to help get the right people to view it.

Comment: try using `classOneSet[i].className`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName` method returns a live list of elements. When you change the class of the first element it will be removed from the list. When you try to change the second element it has moved to the first position in the list and you won't find it at the second position. If you had more than two elements to change, you would see that it changed every other element.

If you loop backwards through the list it works:

```js
window.onload = function(){

  //Get elements for class: one_level
  var classOneSet = document.getElementsByClassName("one_level");
  var lengthList = classOneSet.length;

  //Change appearance
  var i;
  for (i = lengthList - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    classOneSet.item(i).className = "four_level";
  }

};
```

```css
.four_level { background: red; }
```

```html
        <ul>
            <li class="one_level">ONE</li>
            <li class="one_level">TWO</li>
            <li class="two_level">THREE</li>
            <li class="two_level">FOUR</li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Thnx... My doubt is cleared

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `item`, treat it like a classic array:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < lengthList; i++){
    classOneSet[i].className = "four_level";
}
```